# Bitmap size exceed VM budget

Tags: android

I have read those posts on this issue but my case is abit different as I am NOT DISPLAYING the bitmap but just post-processing the image from raw data.
First, I call `ImageProcessing.rgbToBitmap(data,width, height);` which will return a Bitmap object. Then I perform these 3 functions SEPARATELY.

1. Rotate Bitmap
2. Add a watermark overlay to Bitmap
3. Add date at lower right hand corner of Bitmap

All 3 methods called will create an return a Bitmap object which probably causes the crash as I am trying to save an image every 1000ms! Sometimes the images saved are distorted probably due to the memory error.

I am posting my codes below and any advices are greatly appreciated. I do not want to compromise on the quality on the image taken though. (Need to preserve the resolution)

```
public static Bitmap addWatermark(Resources res, Bitmap source) {
        int w, h;
        Canvas c;
        Paint paint;
        Bitmap bmp, watermark;

        Matrix matrix;
        float scale;
        RectF r;

        w = source.getWidth();
        h = source.getHeight();

        // Create the new bitmap
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG
                | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);

        // Copy the original bitmap into the new one
        c = new Canvas(bmp);
        c.drawBitmap(source, 0, 0, paint);

        // Load the watermark
        watermark = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.watermark);
        // Scale the watermark to be approximately 10% of the source image
        // height
        scale = (float) (((float) h * 0.80) / (float) watermark.getHeight());

        // Create the matrix
        matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale);
        // Determine the post-scaled size of the watermark
        r = new RectF(0, 0, watermark.getWidth(), watermark.getHeight());
        matrix.mapRect(r);
        // Center watermark
        matrix.postTranslate((w - r.width()) / 2, (h - r.height()) / 2);

        // Draw the watermark
        c.drawBitmap(watermark, matrix, paint);
        // Free up the bitmap memory
        watermark.recycle();

        return bmp;
    }

public static Bitmap addDate(Bitmap src, String date) {
        int w = src.getWidth();
        int h = src.getHeight();
        //Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());
        Bitmap result = src;
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

        Paint paint = new Paint(); 
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 185, 15)); 
        paint.setTextSize(20);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawText(date, w - 200, h - 20, paint);

        return result;
    }
public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap src, int rotation) {

        int width = src.getWidth();
        int height = src.getHeight();

        // create a matrix for the manipulation
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // rotate the Bitmap
        matrix.postRotate(rotation);

        // recreate the new Bitmap, swap width and height and apply
        // transform
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, width, height,
                matrix, true);
        return rotatedBitmap;

    }
```

Comment: recycle() is probably your answer ... android is pretty strict about this..

Answer (score 0):

Try this first:
Change

```
// Copy the original bitmap into the new one
c = new Canvas(bmp);
c.drawBitmap(source, 0, 0, paint);
```

with

```
// Copy the original bitmap into the new one
c = new Canvas(bmp);
bmp.recycle(); //here or below
c.drawBitmap(source, 0, 0, paint);
//below bmp.recycle();
```

and here:

```
canvas.drawText(date, w - 200, h - 20, paint);

return result;
```

with

```
canvas.drawText(date, w - 200, h - 20, paint);
result.recycle();
return result;
```

and here

```
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, width, height,
                matrix, true);
return rotatedBitmap;
```

with

```
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, width, height,
                matrix, true);
return rotatedBitmap;
rotatedBitmap.recycle();
```

Add all this (recycle();) maybe this is already enough and also try the code with smaller bitmaps, en see if it still crashes (like 50px by 50px).

And no, their is no way to increase the VM of your phone.

Comment: is there a easier way to do it? because I need to apply the watermark on the entire bitmap. I do not know how to process (apply watermark) on the smaller chunks...

Comment: it depends on the configuration set by user. i generate a list dynamically base on the support of the device. as i am using the image preview sizes, the highest resolution i see from my samsung s1 is 1280 x 720.

Comment: I am using S1. or is there a way to increase the application's vm heap size? Tried to search but it seems like it must be adjusted through a root OS.

Comment: i appreciate your help, but i've tried. it's not working. we cannot recycle the bmp as we are still using them.

Comment: and if you try small images (like 50px by 50 px)? with your original code

Comment: yes i am able to get through if the resolutions used are smaller. the processor is not fast enough to have those images(bigger resolution) saved... i am trying to save the frames per 1000ms. if there is no way out, i will increase the frame saving rate to 2000ms and reducing the resolution!

Comment: Well, I don't know how to use my previous code, of putting everything into chucks, together with a watermark. so or reducing, or maybe someone else got an answer.